# 'Could not find us.bpsm:edn-java:0.4.3' error with Gradle for Clojure (Clojuresque)

Tags: clojure, gradle, clojuresque

I'm trying to use Gradle for Clojure (Clojuresque), I have this `build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories { maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" } }
    dependencies { classpath "clojuresque:clojuresque:1.7.0" }
}

apply plugin: 'clojure'

repositories {
    maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" }
}
```

When I execute `gradle tasks`, I have errors. I checked that there is no `http://clojars.org/repo/us/bpsm` directory. What might be wrong?

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find us.bpsm:edn-java:0.4.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
         http://clojars.org/repo/us/bpsm/edn-java/0.4.3/edn-java-0.4.3.pom
         http://clojars.org/repo/us/bpsm/edn-java/0.4.3/edn-java-0.4.3.jar
     Required by:
         :clojure:unspecified > clojuresque:clojuresque:1.7.0 > clojuresque:clojuresque-nrepl:1.1.0 > clojuresque:clojuresque-common:1.1.0
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:1.8.9.
     Searched in the following locations:
         http://clojars.org/repo/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.9/groovy-1.8.9.pom
         http://clojars.org/repo/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.9/groovy-1.8.9.jar
     Required by:
         :clojure:unspecified > clojuresque:clojuresque:1.7.0 > clojuresque:clojuresque-nrepl:1.1.0 > de.kotka.gradle:gradle-utils:0.2.2 > de.kotka.groovy:zweig:0.4.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing artifact is located in maven central repository. The following script works fine:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { 
      maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" } 
      mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies { classpath "clojuresque:clojuresque:1.7.0" }
}

apply plugin: 'clojure'

repositories {
    maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" }
}
```

Comment: and adding it to the second repositories would not hurt either (or `jcenter()`)