# Using gradle/clojuresq to build clojure

Tags: jar, clojure, gradle, clojuresque

I'm trying to use gradle/Clojuresque to build clojure code, run it, and get uberjar. 
I use hints from http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Getting+Started+with+Gradle, https://bitbucket.org/kotarak/clojuresque/wiki/Getting%20Started, and ['Could not find us.bpsm:edn-java:0.4.3' error with Gradle for Clojure (Clojuresque)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000395/could-not-find-us-bpsmedn-java0-4-3-error-with-gradle-for-clojure-clojuresq).

This is the grade script.

```
buildscript {
    repositories { 
        maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" } 
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "clojuresque:clojuresque:1.7.0" 
    }
}

apply plugin: 'clojure'

clojure.aotCompile = true

repositories {
    flatDir dirs: project.file("lib/runtime")
    maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" }
}
```

With `gradle build` task, there is no error and I have a jar file, but I don't see any class file generated; I don't think the generated jar contains nothing, especially when I compared the results from manual build ([Compile clojure source into class (AOT) from command line (not using lein)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011295/compile-clojure-source-into-class-aot-from-command-line-not-using-lein)).

```
.
├── build
│   ├── libs
│   │   └── clojure.jar
│   └── tmp
│       └── jar
│           └── MANIFEST.MF
├── build.gradle
└── src
    └── hello
        └── core.clj
```

This is the core.clj

```
(ns hello.core
  (:gen-class))
(defn -main
  "This should be pretty simple."
  []
  (println "Hello, World!"))
```

What might be wrong? Also, how to run the code and get uberjar like `lein run` and `lein uberjar` does?

I zipped the directory in https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10773282/share/2015/clojure_test.zip

Comment: Could you please provide a sample project on github?

Comment: @Opal: I'm not sure if need a sample project, because it has only two files (gradle) and core.clj and the code is in the problem.

Comment: I don't know how to set it all up. If I had a sample project I would try, without it, it's problematic. However there are users who probably know the solution.

Comment: @Opal: I zipped the directory and uploaded in the Dropbox.

Comment: I see that you've worked it out, I also added configured project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Create the class files

The source code should be located in `./src/main/clojure` as it is the default directory.

One can specify source file in gradle file, though.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        clojure {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}
```

The other issue was with missing dependencies:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.clojure:clojure:1.6.0"
}
```

`gradle build` will generate the class files.

#### Get the jar file

We need to set the main class for the jar file.

```
jar
{
    manifest.attributes("Main-Class": "hello.core")
}
```

I'm not exactly sure if the setup is quite necessary; `gradle jar` will generate the jar file.

#### execute the jar file

This is the command to run the code:

```
java -cp .:<PATH>/clojure-1.6.0.jar:build/libs/clojure_test.jar hello.core
```

#### uberjar

There are three modifications needed: hints from https://github.com/DevonStrawn/Clojuresque-Boilerplate/blob/master/UberJar/build.gradle.

```
uberjar
{
    manifest.attributes("Main-Class": "hello.core")
}

apply plugin: 'application'

uberjar.enabled = true
```

#### Execute the uberjar

Now just one jar for the execution

```
clojure_test> java -jar build/libs/clojure_test-standalone.jar 
Hello, World!
```

#### The new build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories { 
        maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" } 
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "clojuresque:clojuresque:1.7.0" 
    }
}

apply plugin: 'clojure'

clojure.aotCompile = true

sourceSets {
    main {
        clojure {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.clojure:clojure:1.7.0"
}

jar
{
    manifest.attributes("Main-Class": "hello.core")
}   

uberjar
{
    manifest.attributes("Main-Class": "hello.core")
}

apply plugin: 'application'

uberjar.enabled = true
```

#### Shadow jar

From Opal's answer, I add the gradle script that create shadowJar. It contains the MAINFEST file that sets up the Main-Class.

```
buildscript {
    repositories { 
        maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" } 
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "clojuresque:clojuresque:1.7.0" 
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'clojure'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

clojure.aotCompile = true
mainClassName = 'hello.core'

sourceSets {
    main {
        clojure {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.clojure:clojure:1.7.0" 
}
```

Or use these two lines of code instead of the manifest change code:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'hello.core'
```

#### Execute the shadow jar

Get the ubjer jar

```
gradle shadow
```

It's the same as uberjar.

```
clojure_test> java -jar build/libs/clojure_test-all.jar 
Hello, World!
```

#### References

- https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow
- Boiler plate -  https://github.com/DevonStrawn/Clojuresque-Boilerplate
- [Building a uberjar with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986244/building-a-uberjar-with-gradle)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing maven central repository:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { 
        maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" } 
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "clojuresque:clojuresque:1.7.0" 
    }
}

apply plugin: 'clojure'

clojure.aotCompile = true

repositories {
    flatDir dirs: project.file("lib/runtime")
    maven { url "http://clojars.org/repo" }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.clojure:clojure:1.6.0" 
}
```

And you both modify gradle source sets or move `hello/core.clj` to `src/main/clojure` where gradle by default looks for sources. With these changes jar file is generated and can be run when valid cp provided - I've no clojure installed so can't check it easily.

**EDIT**

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/29015575) a sample project can be found that has all the changes I introduced. It also produces uber jar with `shadowJar` task that has clojure dependency built-in and can enables `hello.core` to be run with the following command:

```
java -cp build/libs/29015575-all.jar hello.core
```

**EDIT2**

Now the github example produces runnable jar.